# Master Node not elected in three node cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I have started elasticsearch with three node,Node1,Node2,Node3. just try to test failover, I killed the node1. but after killing the node. Master is not automatically elected as it should be.
Getting following error after removing the Node1 at Node2. 
Details exception.

```
[2020-01-18 11:47:40,041][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [node-2] removed {{node-0}{G2g0pv6BSVe1rEBsO-QIbw}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{master=true},}, reason: zen-disco-master_failed ({node-0}{G2g0pv6BSVe1rEBsO-QIbw}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{master=true})
[2020-01-18 11:47:40,057][WARN ][discovery.zen.ping.unicast] [node-2] failed to send ping to [{node-0}{G2g0pv6BSVe1rEBsO-QIbw}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{master=true}]
RemoteTransportException[[node-0][127.0.0.1:9300][internal:discovery/zen/unicast]]; nested: IllegalStateException[received ping request while not started];
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: received ping request while not started
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.unicast.UnicastZenPing.handlePingRequest(UnicastZenPing.java:497)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.unicast.UnicastZenPing.access$2400(UnicastZenPing.java:83)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.unicast.UnicastZenPing$UnicastPingRequestHandler.messageReceived(UnicastZenPing.java:522)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.unicast.UnicastZenPing$UnicastPingRequestHandler.messageReceived(UnicastZenPing.java:518)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportRequestHandler.messageReceived(TransportRequestHandler.java:33)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:77)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handleRequest(MessageChannelHandler.java:227)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:116)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
```

```
master-Node-setting
```

```
    cluster.name: sample_cluster
    node.name: Node-1
    node.master: true
    node.data: false
    index.number_of_shards: 0
    index.number_of_replicas: 0
    bootstrap.mlockall: true
    discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
    discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
    discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["Node-1:9300", "node-2:9301",node-3:9302]
```

Comment: Please share your configuration (especially discovery and network)

Comment: which version of ES u are using?

Comment: @user7851946 I am using elasticsearch2.4 version.

Comment: Do all nodes see each other 9200,9300 ports?

Comment: @ibexit I have update the settings

Comment: What version are you on @shiv?

Comment: @ibexit 2.4 elasticsearch

Comment: Thanks, can you share the transport ip, hostname and port for all master nodes too?

Comment: @ibexit i am running at localhost machine

Comment: It seems, that the cluster formation was not ready as at least one node is not ready yet. Let us verify some stuff: Have you defined a different data path for each instance? Have you defined a different transport port for each node? Can you verify the cluster state is green before test? Can you verify all nodes are joined as expexted? Here are some background informations:  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/modules-node.html https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/modules-network.html https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/clus

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/cluster-nodes-info.html